# Navigation Advices from SKMaps 2.5.1 always in English

Tags: android, localization, skmaps

The navigation advices obtained from SKNavigationManager always are in English.
For example: (German language case)
The sound advices are correctly received in german but the text advices are still in English. It's strange because if you exchange general_TTS.csv by general.csv config file you can get text advices in german but the sound advices are not received.

Can you help me with some workaround?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now both audio advices and text advices are created from the same config files making in so that readable text advices (instructions) will only be generated when using the TTS (text to speech) option - when using the "audio files" option you will only get a chain of English file names that indicate what audio files should be played (the content of those audio files will be in German but their names are in English).

So in your scenario, use

```
advisorSettings.setAdvisorType(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorType.TEXT_TO_SPEECH);
```

for the desired result.

More info about the audio/text instruction config file: [here](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/) and [here](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-faq/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the [german files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k16z4npyl47218f/AAB-KL0qwfOVhFTeN11V4HNva?dl=0) into your src/main/assets/SKMaps.zip/Advisor/Languages/de/sound_files folder?

How do you initialize SKAdvisorSettings? Like this

```
SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(this);
```

or with a custom SKMapsInitSettings?

Comment: Exactly like you in DemoUtils.java in initializeLibrary() method but with:
advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_DE);

advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("de");

advisorSettings.setAdvisorType(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorType.AUDIO_FILES);

Comment: Do you also use:
advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(getMapResourcesDirPath() + "Advisor");
advisorSettings.setResourcePath(mapResourcesDirPath + "Advisor/Languages");
?

Comment: Yes, I am using it. Indeed the audio advices are correctly speech in german, the problem are the text instructions (they still in english). getAdviceInstruction() from SKNavigationState :)

Comment: I use my own post-processed instructions. Therefore, I can not help in this regard - sorry